# Differential op-amp battery cell monitor circuit odd behavior

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-monitor

I'm working on a three cell LIPO battery cell voltage monitor using three differential op-amps.

I had the circuit I designed below printed on a PCB and have assembled the board, but I am getting strange results on the output of op-amp 1 (Op1_output.) Op2_Output and Op3_Output work as expected.

When connected to the 3 cell LIPO (cell voltage for each cell = 3.8V,) Op1_output is reading 4.6V as opposed to the expected 3.8V. I have tested all the connections and also soldered 3 separate boards in case there was an issue with my connections, but the results are always the same.

I know that I can simply read the 3.8V directly because that cell is the first in the series, but I'm curious as to what my issue is, as creating the circuit in a simulator is yielding the expected results.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

[Op-amp datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2201061630_COSINE-COS5532SR_C693059.pdf)

[image: Circuit_Diagram]

[image]

[image]

Comment: examine R10 in the schematic

Comment: What's the minimum potential difference between the opamp rails?

Comment: @jsotola - R10 is connected to B3+, which the same as Vcc. Should be fine. It’s op1 that’s malfunctioning.

Comment: Very odd opamp choice. 5532s are more at home in mixing desks and hi-fi amplifiers than battery monitoring circuits! Look at "Input common-mode voltage range" in the datasheet and note that you are operating out of spec. You may be looking for rail to rail opamps instead.

Comment: A tip: you can insert Falstad sims right in your text. In Falstad, use ‘Export As Link’, copy the URL, then add that as linkified text.

Comment: Good to know! I don't have much experience sourcing electronics (my background is mechanical engineering). I was under the impression 5532s were rail to rail, I'll have to spend some more time with the datasheets, and find a guide to choosing op amps/chips in general for future work. Do you have any advice for selecting components in general?

Comment: That’s a big topic. Try searching ‘selecting an op amp’ and see what comes up. In this particular case, you’d select one for single-ended and lower voltage with inputs that go to ground. So, an LM324 or a newer cousin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the 5532 datasheet you linked, the input range needs to be Vss+2V to Vdd-2V. Since you’re using ground as your negative supply, this limits the input range to no less than 2V.

With the R3/R4 voltage divider between OP1 and GND, this value isn’t being met on the (+) input of OP1: it’s only 1.9V above GND if BT1 is 3.8V, and as low as 1.5V at BT1 end of discharge (3.0V).

So OP1 is failing. As to exactly why, that is a result of this particular op-amp’s input stage design.

Try an op-amp that includes GND in its input range. The LM324 can do this. It’s popular and cheap.

So why doesn’t the sim fail? The Falstad simulator uses an ‘ideal’ op-amp which has no such input range limitations. However, if you try the Falstad 741 model it will fail; it’s similar to the 5532. There’s also an LM324 model you can try.

Or, you can get rid of the resistors R1, R2 and R4 and just wire the op-amp as a follower. Then the (+) input will be the same as the BT1 voltage, 3.0 to 3.8V or so, and (-) will follow it.

Still another option is to just measure BT1 directly. Since it’s referenced to GND there isn’t a need to use a differential amp. Save the one part, solve the problem. Win-win.

Not sure what your intention is with the 7809 driving an LED, but the overhead voltage for that regulator is 2-3V. That means it’ll be at only be outputting ~7V at the end-of-discharge voltage of 9V (3.0V per cell).

Comment: Ah of course, I figured it was something obvious that I was missing. That fixed it! Thank you. This is the first proper circuit I designed and I think I got overwhelmed by all the new processes and data. Thanks again!